# jQuery Form Wizard: Move to other input and make it scroll to focused input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I have used [jQuery Form Wizard](http://thecodemine.org/) and create a method for navigate to other `input` in some `form`.

```
function goto(id_step, id_input)
{
    $('#demoForm').formwizard('show', id_step);
    //unfocus first input
    $("#demoForm").formwizard({ 
        focusFirstInput : false
    });
    $('#'+id_input).focus();
}
goto('info', 'res_umur');
```

The function is ok, but the focus method  doesn't scroll to focused `input` element. Anyone know how to make it scroll?

Comment: Can you post a (simple/minimal) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce your problem, and also make it easier for us to help you (since we don't have to recreate a demo for ourselves).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView)

```
$('#'+id_input)[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Modify your code:

```
function goto(id_step, id_input)
{
    $('#demoForm').formwizard('show', id_step);
    //unfocus first input
    $("#demoForm").formwizard({ 
        focusFirstInput : false
    });
    $('#'+id_input).focus();
    $('#'+id_input)[0].scrollIntoView();
}
goto('info', 'res_umur');
```

Comment: Thanks, it work now, I just need to wrap the function to `setTimeout` function. `setTimeout(function(){$('#res_umur')[0].scrollIntoView()},200);`